# Command to convert "" in CSV to \"

Tags: csv, sed, awk, amazon-redshift

From an external source, I get huge CSV files (around 16GB), that have fields optionally enclosed in double quotes ("). Fields are separated by semicolon (;). When a field contains a double quote in the content, it is escaped as two double quotes.

Currently, I am importing these into a MySQL database, that understands the semantics of `""`.

I am considering a migration to Amazon Redshift, but they (or probably PostgreSQL in general) demand quotes to be escaped with a backslash as `\"`.

Now I am searching for the **fastest command line tool** (probably awk, sed?) and the exact syntax to convert my files.

Example input:

```
"""start of line";"""beginning "" middle and end """;"end of line"""
12345;"Tell me an ""intelligent"" joke; I tell you one in return"
54321;"Your mom is ""nice"""
"";"";""
"However, if;""Quotes""; are present"
```

Example output:

```
"\"start of line";"\"beginning \" middle and end \"";"end of line\""
12345;"Tell me an \"intelligent\" joke; I tell you one in return"
54321;"Your mom is \"nice\""
"";"";""
"However, if;\"Quotes\"; are present"
```

**Edit:** Added more tests.

Comment: I believe the issues you were experiencing might now be handled natively. On Aug 9 AWS announced that they were "adding support for standard CSV double quote escaping".

See post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2064

I would be interested in your results if you are able to test and verify this new feature functions as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of edge cases to be aware of:

- what if doubled double-quotes are at the beginning of a string?
- What if that string is the first field?
- a field containing an empty string

```
sed -r '
    # at the start of a line or the start of a field, 
    # replace """ with "\"
    s/(^|;)"""/\1"\\"/g

    # replace any doubled double-quote with an escaped double-quote.
    # this affects any "inner" quote pair as well as end of field or end of line
    # if there is an escaped quote from the previous command, don't be fooled by
    # a proceeding quote.
    s/([^\\])""/\1\\"/g

    # the above step will destroy empty strings. fix them here.  this uses a
    # conditional loop: if there are 2 consecutive empty fields, they will
    # share a delimited, so we have to process the line more than once
    :fix_empty_fields
    s/(^|;)\\"($|;)/\1""\2/g
    tfix_empty_fields
' <<'END'

"""start of line";"""beginning "" middle and end """;"end of line"""
"";"";"";"""";"""""";"";""

END
```

```
"\"start of line";"\"beginning \" middle and end \"";"end of line\""
"";"";"";"\"";"\"\"";"";""
```

Sed is an efficient tool, but it will take a while with 16GB files. And you better have at least 16GB free disk space to write the updated files (even sed's `-i` inplace-edit uses temp files behind the scenes)

refs: [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/), [sed looping commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Programming-Commands.html#Programming-Commands)

Comment: Thanks, I added your special cases to the test input. It works gret. Copying the 16GB file takes 3m21s and sed with write to file took 4m34s, really fast!

Comment: For empty fields in the middle, yes. For empty first or last fields, no. I think it might not be possible without lookbehinds, which sed cannot handle?

Comment: As noted above, on Aug 9 AWS announced that they were "adding support for standard CSV double quote escaping". See post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2064

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sed`, as you suggest in your post:

```
$ sed 's@""@\\"@g' input
12345;"Tell me an \"intelligent\" joke; I tell you one in return"
54321;"Your mom is \"nice\""
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for using sed:

```
$ sed 's:"":\\":g' your_csv.csv
```

When testing it on the following:

```
new """
test ""
"hows "" this "" "
```

I got:

```
new \""
test \"
"hows \" this \" "
```

Answer (score 0):

this line should work:

```
sed 's/""/\\"/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/""/\\"/g' input_file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat n.txt 
12345;"Tell me an ""intelligent"" joke; I tell you one in return"
54321;"Your mom is ""nice"""

$ sed 's/""/\\"/g' n.txt 
12345;"Tell me an \"intelligent\" joke; I tell you one in return"
54321;"Your mom is \"nice\""
```